# Slider Door locks from inside but not outside with key

Tags: doors, lock

I  can lock my slider from inside with no problem but when i try to lock it from the outside with the key (I have tried several keys) it does not lock but I can see the hook go up the same as it does when I lock it from inside so before I take it apart again does anyone have any thoughts?
It is a new handle and lock and has worked fine for months until today

Comment: PICTURE OF THE INSIDE WOULD HELP.